# Scipy - two tail ppf function for a z value?

Tags: python, scipy

Using the `ppf` function from `scipy.stat.norm`, I get a one-tail result, for example, `ppf(.95)` gives off `1.644...` rather than `1.96...` a two-tail distribution should get.

Is there a function in scipy that gives off a two-tailed z-score based on the p-value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you're looking for is quite simply

```
In [12]: def normz(val):
   ....:     return scipy.stats.norm.ppf((1+val)/2)
   ....: 
In [13]: normz(0.95)
Out[13]: 1.959963984540054
```

This is because of the symmetric nature of the normal distribution. A 95% confidence interval covers 95% of the normal curve, and as a result the probability of acquiring a value outside this 95% is less than 5% (*due to its shape*). Then recalling that the normal curve is symmetric, the area in each tail is equivalent to

[image]

so in your case, the area in each tail is `0.025`.

As a result, in order to use `scipy.stats.normal.ppf()` with `C`, you must use the ***symmetric*** nature of the normal distribution and

[image]

to obtain a suitable lower/upper tail probability `0.975` to use with `scipy.stats.norm.ppf()`. This graph could help you visualize the concept.

[image]