# Pandas Series correlation against a single vector

Tags: performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a list of arrays as one column.

```
  import pandas as pd

  v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  v1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  v2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  v3 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

  df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [v1, v2, v3]})

  print df
```

Output:

```
                       A
0  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I want to do a pd.Series.corr for each row of df.A against the single vector v.
I'm currently doing a loop on df.A and achieving it. It is very slow.

Expected Output:

```
                       A         B
0  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  -0.612372 
1  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]  -0.158114
2  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]  -0.288675
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one using the correlation defintion with NumPy tools meant for performance with [`corr2_coeff_rowwise`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703623/) -

```
a = np.array(df.A.tolist()) # or np.vstack(df.A.values)
df['B'] = corr2_coeff_rowwise(a, np.asarray(v)[None])
```

Runtime test -

Case #1 : 1000 rows

```
In [59]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.random.randint(0,9,(7)) for i in range(1000)]})

In [60]: v = np.random.randint(0,9,(7)).tolist()

# @jezrael's soln
In [61]: %timeit df['new'] = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist()).corrwith(pd.Series(v), axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 142 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit df['B'] = corr2_coeff_rowwise(np.array(df.A.tolist()), np.asarray(v)[None])
1000 loops, best of 3: 461 µs per loop
```

Case #2 : 10000 rows

```
In [63]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.random.randint(0,9,(7)) for i in range(10000)]})

In [64]: v = np.random.randint(0,9,(7)).tolist()

# @jezrael's soln
In [65]: %timeit df['new'] = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist()).corrwith(pd.Series(v), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.38 s per loop

In [66]: %timeit df['B'] = corr2_coeff_rowwise(np.array(df.A.tolist()), np.asarray(v)[None])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.05 ms per loop
```

Comment: `np.array(df.A.tolist())` _may_ be faster.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Looks faster! Thanks.

Comment: Please start answering more pandas questions... *phew*

Answer (score 2):

Use [`corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html), but if performance is important, [Divakar's anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47484726/2901002) should be faster:

```
df['new'] = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist()).corrwith(pd.Series(v), axis=1)
print (df)
                       A       new
0  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -0.612372
1  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] -0.158114
2  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] -0.288675
```