# Shuffling rows of large pandas DataFrame and correlation with a series

Tags: performance, pandas, numpy, permutation, correlation

I need to independently shuffle each row of large pandas DataFrames several times (the typical shape is `(10000,1000)`) and then estimate the correlation of each row with a given series.

The most efficient (=quick) way I found to do it staying within pandas is the following:

```
for i in range(N): #the larger is N, the better it is
    df_sh = df.apply(numpy.random.permutation, axis=1)
    #where df this is my large dataframe, with 10K rows and 1K columns

    corr = df_sh.corrwith(s, axis = 1)
    #where s is the provided series (shape of s =(1000,))
```

The two tasks take approximately the same amount of time (namely 30 secs each). I tried to convert my dataframe into a `numpy.array`, to perform a `for` loop over the array and, for each line, I first perform the permutation and then measure the correlation with `scipy.stats.pearsonr`. I unfortunately managed to speed up my two tasks only by a factor 2.
There would be other viable options to speed up the tasks even more?  (NB: I am already parallelizing with `Joblib` the execution of my code up to the maximum factor allowed by the machine I am using).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Correlation between a 2D matrix/array and 1D array/vector :

We can adapt [`corr2_coeff_rowwise`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703623/) for correlation between a `2D` array/matrix and a 1D array/vector, like so -

```
def corr2_coeff_2d_1d(A, B):
    # Rowwise mean of input arrays & subtract from input arrays themeselves
    A_mA = A - A.mean(1,keepdims=1)
    B_mB = B - B.mean()

    # Sum of squares across rows
    ssA = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A_mA,A_mA)
    ssB = B_mB.dot(B_mB)

    # Finally get corr coeff
    return A_mA.dot(B_mB)/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)
```

To shuffle each row and do this for all rows, we can make use of `np.random.shuffle`. Now, this shuffle function works along the first axis. So, to solve our case, we need to feed in the transposed version. Also, note that this shuffling would be done in-place. So, if original dataframe is needed elsewhere, do make a copy before processing. Thus, the solution would be -

Hence, let's use this to solve our case -

```
# Extract underlying arry data for faster NumPy processing in loop later on    
a = df.values  
s_ar = s.values

# Setup array for row-indexing with NumPy's advanced indexing later on
r = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]

for i in range(N):
    # Get shuffled indices per row with `rand+argsort/argpartition` trick from -
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438143/
    idx = np.random.rand(*a.shape).argsort(1)

    # Shuffle array data with NumPy's advanced indexing
    shuffled_a = a[r, idx]

    # Compute correlation
    corr = corr2_coeff_2d_1d(shuffled_a, s_ar)
```

#### Optimized version #1

Now, we could pre-compute for the parts involving the series that stays the same between iterations. Hence, a further optimized version would look like this -

```
a = df.values  
s_ar = s.values
r = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]

B = s_ar
B_mB = B - B.mean()
ssB = B_mB.dot(B_mB)

A = a
A_mean = A.mean(1,keepdims=1)

for i in range(N):
    # Get shuffled indices per row with `rand+argsort/argpartition` trick from -
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438143/
    idx = np.random.rand(*a.shape).argsort(1)

    # Shuffle array data with NumPy's advanced indexing
    shuffled_a = a[r, idx]

    # Compute correlation
    A = shuffled_a
    A_mA = A - A_mean
    ssA = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A_mA,A_mA)
    corr = A_mA.dot(B_mB)/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)
```

---

#### Benchmarking

**Setup inputs with actual use-case shapes/sizes**

```
In [302]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000,1000))

In [303]: s = pd.Series(df.iloc[0])
```

**1. Original method**

```
In [304]: %%timeit
     ...: df_sh = df.apply(np.random.permutation, axis=1)
     ...: corr = df_sh.corrwith(s, axis = 1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.99 s per loop
```

**2. Proposed method**

The pre-processing part (only done once before starting loop, so not including in timings) -

```
In [305]: a = df.values  
     ...: s_ar = s.values
     ...: r = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
     ...: 
     ...: B = s_ar
     ...: B_mB = B - B.mean()
     ...: ssB = B_mB.dot(B_mB)
     ...: 
     ...: A = a
     ...: A_mean = A.mean(1,keepdims=1)
```

Part of proposed solution that runs in loop -

```
In [306]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = np.random.rand(*a.shape).argsort(1)
     ...: shuffled_a = a[r, idx]
     ...: 
     ...: A = shuffled_a
     ...: A_mA = A - A_mean
     ...: ssA = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A_mA,A_mA)
     ...: corr = A_mA.dot(B_mB)/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)
1 loop, best of 3: 675 ms per loop
```

Thus, we are seeing a speedup of around **`3x`** here!

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow and let you know, but it sounds very promising, I had not thought of randomizing the index of the matrix rather than the entries.

Comment: At the beginning I went for `np.random.shuffle(a.T)` as well but unfortunately I realized that it wasn't randomizing each line independently i.e. it does `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] -> [[1,3,2],[4,6,5]]` if the i-th entries of line k is moved to position j then position i of line h will be move in the same position, that is why I was looping on `a` using your notation. I can't find a way to avoid to perform such loop.

Comment: and that's why I liked your original answer which was randomizing  indexes.