# Numpy Rolling Columwise Correlation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numba

I have two matrices with the same shape:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
np.random.seed(10)
a = np.random.random(30).reshape(10,3)
b = np.random.random(30).reshape(10,3)
```

i.e., 10 rows and three columns. I need the *rolling* correlation of the columns with the same column index in each matrix. The slow way is:

```
def roll_corr((a, b), window):
    out = np.ones_like(a)*np.nan
    for i in xrange(window-1, a.shape[0]):
        #print "%d --> %d" % ((i-(window-1)), i)
        for j in xrange(a.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = pearsonr(
                a[(i-(window-1)):(i), j], b[(i-(window-1)):(i), j]
            )[0]
    return out
```

With results for `roll_corr((a, b), 5)` as I want,

```
array([[        nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan],
       [        nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 0.28810753,  0.27836622,  0.88397851],
       [-0.04076151,  0.45254981,  0.83259104],
       [ 0.62262963, -0.4188768 ,  0.35479134],
       [ 0.13130652, -0.91441413, -0.21713372],
       [ 0.54327228, -0.91390053, -0.84033286],
       [ 0.45268257, -0.95245888, -0.50107515]])
```

The question is: **is there a more idiomatic numpy way to do this? Vectorized? Strides trick? Numba?**

I have searched but have not found this. I no not want to use pandas; must be numpy.

Comment: Did either one of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to get sliding windows. [More info on use of `as_strided` based `view_as_windows`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890064/)

Thus, we would have one solution based on [`corr2_coeff_rowwise`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41703623/), like so -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

A = view_as_windows(a,(window,1))[...,0]
B = view_as_windows(b,(window,1))[...,0]

A_mA = A - A.mean(-1, keepdims=True)
B_mB = B - B.mean(-1, keepdims=True)

## Sum of squares across rows
ssA = (A_mA**2).sum(-1) # or better : np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',A_mA,A_mA)
ssB = (B_mB**2).sum(-1) # or better : np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',B_mB,B_mB)

## Finally get corr coeff
out = np.full(a.shape, np.nan)
out[window-1:] = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',A_mA,B_mB)/np.sqrt(ssA*ssB)
```

Comment: On large amount of data using  np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided may lead to Memory error. So this solution is useful but only for comparatively small arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas.rolling_curr() function to generate the correlation. I can't see why they give different outputs, though.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

np.random.seed(10)
a = np.random.random(30).reshape(10,3)
b = np.random.random(30).reshape(10,3)

a_1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b_1 = pd.DataFrame(b)

print pd.rolling_corr(arg1=a_1, arg2=b_1, window=5)

# OUTPUT
===============================
   0         1         2
0  NaN       NaN       NaN 
1  NaN       NaN       NaN
2  NaN       NaN       NaN
3  NaN       NaN       NaN
4  0.441993  0.254435  0.707801 
5  0.314446  0.233392  0.425191
6  0.243755 -0.441434  0.352801
7  0.281139 -0.864357 -0.192409
8  0.543645 -0.925822 -0.563786
9  0.445918 -0.784808 -0.532234
```

Comment: In newer versions of pandas, there is pd.rolling() function which is a bit different

Comment: Do you know how this would be done with the new `rolling` syntax? That syntax is a method of a single dataframe; i.e., it is not pd.rolling(), it is df.rolling()...; so here something like a_1.rolling(5,5)...  but how to make it column by column with b1?

Comment: I think one way to do it can be to vectorize both matrices as (30,1) then concatenate them. I am not so familiar with it, though.